# Internal server error 500 in particular pages

Tags: magento-1.9, error, register, password

I have setup a store in magento and i am getting the HTTP internal server error 500 in **createpost** page that is after a customer clicks on submit button in the **register page** and in **forgotpasswordpost** that is after a customer enters email and click on submit button in the **forgot password page**. and once I hit back a normal message is being shown saying "Thank you for registering" All other pages are working fine. How can I sort this out kindly help me with this.

Comment: in root of magento, you can see `index.php` file, you  can uncomment these line : `#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);` & check error

Comment: @BabyinMagento Yes i did the same and the mbstring extension was missing in my server installed it and it solved my error thank you. If you can write the same as answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In root of magento, you can see `index.php` file, you can un comment these lines in that file :

```
#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);,
```

Then you can see the real errors that causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Increase Php memory limit in `.htaccess` file located in root In my case I am using

`php_value memory_limit 1024M`

And then clear your cache and check again, hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi murtaza, Thank you for the reply,  I did the same before but it did not work out for me. mbstring extension was missing in my server and i found out that when I uncommented the #ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1); in index.php file in root as suggested Baby in magento and after i installed that extension everything worked for me properly.

Comment: Ok , Your problem is solved that's it :)